# How to refer to the exact object

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need a script that will change status to 0 for every student that has 3 or more absences

This is what I came up with:

```
UPDATE Group_cast
SET gc_Status = CASE WHEN ((SELECT COUNT(at_Presence) 
    FROM Attendance INNER JOIN Student ON at_stID = st_ID 
        INNER JOIN Group_cast ON st_ID = gc_stID 
    WHERE at_Presence = 0) >= 3) THEN 0
ELSE 1 END;
```

but it's updating every student status to 0 on the list and not just the one with 3 or more absences.

Comment: There's no `JOIN` between your outer reference to `Group_Cast` and your inner reference to it, so it's counting for **every** student.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your subquery has a completely separate reference to `Group_cast` so it's counting a grand total for every Student, not just the one relevant to the row.

With no sample data, or expected results, this is impossible to test, but perhaps this?

```sql
UPDATE GC
SET gc_Status = CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(A.at_Presence) --Guessed the qualifier
                           FROM dbo.Attendance A
                                JOIN dbo.Student S ON A.at_stID = S.st_ID --Guessed the qualifiers
                           WHERE S.st_ID = GC.gc_stID --Guessed the qualifiers
                             AND A.at_Presence = 0) >= 3 THEN 0 --Guessed the qualifier
                     ELSE 1
                END
FROM dbo.Group_cast GC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE Group_cast
set gc_Status =case when absentcnt>=3 then 0 end
from 
(SELECT st_ID,COUNT(at_Presence) absentcnt
    FROM Attendance INNER JOIN Student ON at_stID = st_ID         
    WHERE at_Presence = 0
    group by st_ID)t where t.st_id=Group_cast.gc_stID
```